# what is failing in my insert query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a form to submit with post, to my table in my database. However whenever I hit submit is says failure. I had several validation scripts that I removed to try and figure out why the form was not submitting.

I checked many of the answered questions regarding INSERT using `mysqli_query`, but none seemed to answer my question. I am aware the HTML structure is probably poor, this is just to get the script working correctly first. its really not complicated, I don't understand whats wrong here.

I have a registration form, and my other forms on the site I'm working on all work fine, update date their tables correctly.  Don't know what I'm missing here.

```
<?php
include('db.php');


$event_name='';
$place='';
$time='';
$date='';
$description=''; 



$event_name=strip_tags($_POST['event_name']);
$place=strip_tags($_POST['place']);
$time=strip_tags($_POST['time']);
$date=strip_tags($_POST['date']);
$description=strip_tags($_POST['event_description']);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO user_posts (title, location, time, date, description)"; 

    $query .= "VALUES ($event_name','$place','$time','$date','$description')";

    if (mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {

        echo "<h2> your post has been submitted </h2>";
        }
    else { 
        die('failure');     
    }
    }
```

and the html form

```
    <body>
   <div class="box-1">
   <form action="create_post_script.php" method="post" id="event_form">

   <div class="box-2">
   <input type="text" name="event_name" placeholder="event title" />   
   </div>

   <div class="box-3">
     <input type="text" name="place" placeholder="location" id="box-3" />
   </div>

    <div class="box-4">
       <input type="time" name="time"  id="box-4" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="box-4">
       <input type="date" name="date" id="box-4" />  
    </div>

    <div class="box-5">
     <h4> <center> ... </center> </h4>
    <textarea class="text-area" name="event_description" id="event_form" >
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" placeholder="submit"/>     
    </div>

    <div class="box-6">
     <div class="box-7">       
     <h4>  </h4>
      </div>
      </div> 

     </form>
     </div>
```

When I hit submit, the resulting page confirms my connection and says 'failure', is this because of the way that I have the submit input field for the `<text-area>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_posts (title, location, time, date, description) "; 

$query .= "VALUES ('$event_name','$place','$time','$date','$description')";
```

Comment: so your problem is solved then accept  my answer and close this question. :)

Comment: yes i will, gotta wait for the 8 minutes or whatever, ugh i stared at that for like an hour and didnt see that

Answer (score 0):

you missing single quotes

```
        <?php

    $query = "INSERT INTO user_posts (title, location, time, date, description)"; 

        $query .= "VALUES ('$event_name','$place','$time','$date','$description')";
      //                  ^^^   
    //              here missing single quotes                 
    echo $query;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code look's fine, but only one thing you're missing a single quote `'` in inserting values.

```
$query .= "VALUES ($event_name','$place','$time','$date','$description')";
```

**Change To**

```
$query .= "VALUES ('$event_name','$place','$time','$date','$description')";
```